# MFC MDI add a second View to a document

Tags: c++, mfc

this is my first question ... 
I need help, because I must add a second View to my document..
I have no idea what can I do more. 
I try it with addView() , etc...

Can anyone help me, please?

PS:  sorry for my bad englisch

Comment: Please read [ask] carefully. Your question will only attract useful answers if you show us your code and describe what is going wrong (error messages? unexpected things happen?).

Answer (score 1):

From your document class implementation:

```
CFrameWnd* pNewFrame=pDocTemplate->CreateNewFrame(this, NULL);
if (pNewFrame == NULL)  return;     // not created
// Optional - Set icon, if the default isn't OK
pNewFrame->SetIcon((HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),  
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(nIDIcon), IMAGE_ICON, 16,16,LR_SHARED), FALSE);
pDocTemplate->InitialUpdateFrame(pNewFrame,this,TRUE);
```

`pDocTemplate` can be obtained from the `new CMultiDocTemplate()` call in the `InitInstance()` member of your `CWinApp`-derived class (just store it).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now I don't know on which method I wrtie the code in the Document class.

Comment: Just at the point where you want the 2nd MDI window/view to be created/displayed, eg in a command handler, after successfully loading the document, after creating it etc etc. It's a matter of the application requirements or design. Only you can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code, MFC does it already for you. (Click on Window-New Window). Here rewritten as a method for the Document Class.

```
bool CMyDoc::AddSecondView()
{
  CMDIChildWnd* pActiveChild = ((CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetMainWnd())->MDIGetActive();    //

  CDocTemplate* pTemplate = GetDocTemplate();
  ASSERT_VALID(pTemplate);
  CFrameWnd* pFrame = pTemplate->CreateNewFrame(this, pActiveChild);
  if (pFrame == NULL)
  {
    return false;     
  }

  pTemplate->InitialUpdateFrame(pFrame, this);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the requirement is found at:
[Creation of Multiple Dynamic Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5295/Creation-of-Multiple-Dynamic-Views-How-to-initiliz)

In short,

1. a new view class is required to be added to application using MFC class wizard.
2. Header of this class is needed to be added into the CPP file of WinApp derived class of your application.
3. Add following code, if your new view class is CMyListView, and header is MyListView.h then use following code. details are in above link.

```
//First add include of your new view to **WinApp** derived class like
#include<MyListView.h>

// In the **InitInstance** function of your WinApp there will be code like
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);

// below this code add your new code as follows,
CMultiDocTemplate* pListDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MYGUITYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyGUIDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyListView));
if (!pListDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pListDocTemplate);
```